# How to get the selected dropdown value using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the selected value in dropdown for edit. But I got all the values in dropdown are selected.

```
    function getinstruments() {

         var model=$('#model').val();
         var brand=$('#brand').val();

         brand = brand.split('%') ;
         model = model.split('%') ;



        $.getJSON("{!! URL::route('appraisal.getinstrument') !!}", {brand: brand[0],model:model[0]}, function(data) {


             if(data.success)
                {
                $('select[name="sub_model"]').find(":selected").html(data.sub_models_array);
                $('select[name="color"]').find(":selected").html(data.colors_array);
                $('select[name="top"]').find(":selected").html(data.top_array);
                $('select[name="neck"]').find(":selected").html(data.neck_array);

                }
            });
        }
```

Don't know what the problem with this code is. Reply of the question is highly appreciated

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xsm-6">    
        <h4>Enter Body wood details</h4>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Top Wood</label>
                <select name='top_wood' class='form-control'  placeholder ='Enter Top wood' id='top'>
                <option value=''>Pick a topWood</option>

                </select>


             </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Back Woord</label>
                <select name='back_wood' class='form-control'  placeholder ='Enter Back wood' id='back'>
                <option value=''>Pick a topWood</option>

                </select>

            </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Neck Wood</label>
                <select name='neck_wood' class='form-control'  placeholder ='Enter Neck wood' id='neck'>
                <option value=''>Pick a NeckWood</option>                   
                </select>

            </div>



        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select color</label>
    <select name='color' class='form-control' id='color' >
                <option value=''>Pick a color</option>

                </select>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Frets</label>
                <select name='frets' class='form-control'  placeholder ='Enter Frets' id='frets'>
                <option value=''>Pick a Fingerboard Material</option>                   
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Turner</label>
                <select name='turner' class='form-control'  placeholder ='Enter Turner' id='turner'>
                <option value=''>Pick a Fingerboard Material</option>                   
                </select>

            </div>
```

this is my view file where i want selected value of dropdaown

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. Can you add some more details to your question?

Comment: Please provide the HTML of your code. A jsfiddle will help a lot.

Comment: I  try to get selected dropdown value in form for edit.using $('select[name="sub_model"]').find(":selected").html(data.sub_models_array); format it is possible to use this code to get selected value in dropdown ? i get the all value in dropdown are selected .

Comment: i just edited my question and there are some part of view file. if u have nay idea please share me

Comment: Are you missing the _wood postfix in your jquery selector?